# Best way to send distance-driven pushs

Tags: javascript

I'm writing an algorithm in javascript, for sending push to users of my application. The application works similar to the transport applications, search the nearest driver. Currently I send scheduled push every 10 seconds for distance between 1 and 5 miles. I'd like to send it first to the nearest one, in case the closest one does not accept send to the second closest and so on, but I do not know how to do this without leaving the server in exile running a task to check if the first driver Accepted to then send to the next.

Were there other ways to carry out this process?

Comment: it sounds like your asking more of an architecture question. I would try posting this question on the [software engineering](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange. [Stack overflow is more of specific problems with a little bit of code. Software engineering is more for whiteboard problems](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254570/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-software-engineering).

Comment: @RicoKahler when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)